# Lightbox and CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, lightbox

I'm trying to add a lightbox plugin to my ckeditor, but it won't work. I downloaded the plugin from [here](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Plugins/Lightbox-plus-for-CKEditor).

When I unzip it I have two files, first file I copy to the CKEditor plugin folder and the other one I copy to my root folder and I include the path to the lightbox_plus.js file in the head of my file. In the lightbox_plus.js file I changed path to the ligthbox folder to *var LightboxPlus_rootpath = '';*

I use custom config file for CKEditor. In in place to config.js I add *config.extraPlugins = 'lightbox';* to my custom file. The file is :

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
config.extraPlugins = 'lightbox';

config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'forms', groups: [ 'forms' ] },
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph' ] },
    { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
    { name: 'links', groups: [ 'links', 'lightbox' ] },
    { name: 'tools', groups: [ 'tools' ] },
    { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
    { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing' ] },
    '/',
    '/',
    { name: 'styles', groups: [ 'styles' ] },
    { name: 'colors', groups: [ 'colors' ] },
    { name: 'others', groups: [ 'others' ] },
    { name: 'about', groups: [ 'about' ] }
];

config.removeButtons = 'Source,Save,Templates,NewPage,Preview,Print,Cut,Copy,Paste,PasteText,PasteFromWord,Find,Replace,SelectAll,Scayt,Form,Checkbox,Radio,TextField,Textarea,Select,HiddenField,ImageButton,BidiLtr,BidiRtl,Language,Flash,PageBreak,About';
```

};

The CKEditor is :

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'txtEmailContent', {
    extraPlugins: 'imageuploader',
    customConfig: 'custom/ckeditor_config.js'
});
```

But nothing happends. I do not see icon for lightbox in the toolbar and I can't do anything.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is CKEditor 3 plugin, and a pretty antique one. If you are using CKEditor 4, try searching for similar functionality in the [CKEditor 4 Add-ons Repository](http://ckeditor.com/addons/plugins/all).

Comment: It's a third-party plugin. If it does not work for you after configuring it according to instructions given by the author, please let the author know in the addon comments. Do note that [some users reported issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116763/ckeditor-and-lightbox-not-work) with it so there is no guarantee that your problem will be fixed.

Comment: I saw that many users have a problem with it, but the author do not answer. That's why I tried to ask for help here.

Comment: If this is the case, and you did not seem to find a working solution either in the comments or on StackOverflow, then you can probably assume it does not work :) Feel free to create your own working solution and share it with the community - lots of users will probably appreciate it!